# Not able to mock/fetch dynamic HTML elements in unit testing for dispatch event

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, addeventlistener

I'm using devextreme elements for lookup operations (`autocomplete`). In `search.componets.ts` am accessing the input elements by using `document.getElementByClassName` for selecting the elements and applying `keyup` event

I have created mock elements in the spec file and tried to fetch and dispatch the keyboard event. But it's not working as excepted.

I have added the component code and component spec code below.

Can anyone help me? or suggest any alternative for this.

**search.component.ts**

```
search() {
const elements = document.getElementByClassName('dx-texteditor-input)
const totalElements = elements?.length
elements[totalElements - 1].addEventListener("keyup", () => {
  this.input = elements[totalElements - 1].value;
});
}
```

**search.component.spec.ts**

```
beforeEach(() => {
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SearchComponent)
const inputMock = `<div id="fixture">
      <input autocomplete="off" aria-label="Search in data grid" class="dx-texteditor-input" type="text" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" role="textbox">
      <input autocomplete="off" aria-label="Search in data grid" class="dx-texteditor-input" type="text" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" role="textbox">
      <input autocomplete="off" aria-label="Search in data grid" class="dx-texteditor-input" type="text" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" role="textbox">
    </div>`;

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', inputMock);
}

it('should check search', () => {
  const keyupEvent = new KeyboardEvent('keyup', { key: 'Enter' });
  const elements = document.querySelector('.dx-texteditor-input') as any;
  elements[0].dispatchEvent(keyupEvent)
  componet.search() 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [MockRender](https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/api/MockRender#example-with-a-custom-template) from [ng-mocks](https://github.com/ike18t/ng-mocks)

Then the whole DOM should be generated like an angular app does it:

```js
it('test', () => {
  const fixture = MockRender(`
    <div id="fixture">
      <input autocomplete="off" aria-label="Search in data grid" class="dx-texteditor-input" type="text" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" role="textbox">
      <input autocomplete="off" aria-label="Search in data grid" class="dx-texteditor-input" type="text" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" role="textbox">
      <input autocomplete="off" aria-label="Search in data grid" class="dx-texteditor-input" type="text" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" role="textbox">
    </div>
    <app-search><!-- should the items be here? --></app-search>
  `);

  // triggers the event on the first element
  ngMocks.trigger('.dx-texteditor-input', 'keyup.enter');

  // asserts
  // ....
});
```